# Combine lists into a single list in R

Tags: r

I have seperate lists such that:

```
1. $text = "I love this product"
2. $text = "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again"
3. $text = "Love this product!!"
```

How could i merge all lists into one list such that:

```
$text = ["I love this product", "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again", "Love this product!!"]
```

I would like to save in in a dataframe such that

```
Product Reviews 
A       ["I love this product", "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again", "Love this product!!"]
B       ["I ......."]
```

`dput` of the list:

```
list(list(text="I love this product"),
     list(text="Amazing service and care given, will visit once again"), 
     list(text="Love this product!!"))
```

When I used cbind, it returns:

```
Reviews
"I love this product"
"Amazing service and care given, will visit once again"
"Love this product!!"
```

instead of what i wanted

Comment: Would you `dput(your_list)` ?

Comment: 1) It looks like you want your final dataframe to include separate rows for different products. If so, please add data for another product to your question so we can see how it’s stored initially. 
2) Do your initial lists include any elements other than $text, and do you want these in your final dataframe? If so please update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution here is to simply `unlist` your list:

```r
list(text = unlist(mylist, use.names = FALSE))
#> $text
#> [1] "I love this product"                                  
#> [2] "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again"
#> [3] "Love this product!!"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We could use `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

my_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(Product = LETTERS[1:n()], .before=1)
```

```
  Product text                                                 
  <chr>   <chr>                                                
1 A       I love this product                                  
2 B       Amazing service and care given, will visit once again
3 C       Love this product!!
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
c(l1,l2,l3) |> sapply(paste0) |>
            unname() |> list(text = _)
```

- output

```
$text
[1] "I love this product"                                  
[2] "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again"
[3] "Love this product!!"
```

- data

```
l1 <- list(text = "I love this product" )
l2 <- list(text = "Amazing service and care given, will visit once again" )
l3 <- list(text = "Love this product!!" )
```

Comment: According to the `dput`, this should be `list(l1, l2, l3)`. That means you don't need the `unname`